# Find data attribute on click - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm clicking a button to remove a hidden class. But it's a dynamic list and I only want to open one of the options Here is my HTML

#### HTML:

```
   <% @assignments.each do |assignment| %>
     <div class="assignments__index__card">

      <div class="assignments__index__options">
        <i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true" data-assignment="<%= assignment.id %>"></i>

        <ul class="assignments__index__options__index <%= assignment.id %> hidden">
          <li><%= link_to "Remove", account_assignment_path(assignment), method: :delete %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Edit", account_assignments_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Here is my JS

### JS

```
window.dashboard = {
  sel: {
    dropdown: $(".fa-list-ul")
  },

  init: function() {
    var _this = this;

    $(document).on("click", _this.sel.dropdown, function(event) {
      debugger;
      $(".assignments__index__options__index").removeClass("hidden")
      $("body").addClass("openDropdown")
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "body.openDropdown", function(event) {
      $(".assignments__index__options__index").addClass("hidden")
      $("body").removeClass("openDropdown")
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }
};

dashboard.init();
```

This problem is I need to pass the data of the assignment to the Javascript

As you can see on click of this class `fa-list-ul` I want to find the data on that class. but this does not work inside the click function:

```
$(this).data("assignment")
```

How do I get the data from this attribute inside the click function?

Comment: Please provide a running snippet (Ctrl+M in editor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change this line:

```
$(document).on("click", _this.sel.dropdown, function(event) {
```

to:

```
$(document).on("click", '.fa-list-ul', function (event) {
```

```js
window.dashboard = {
  sel: {
    dropdown: $(".fa-list-ul")
  },

  init: function() {
    var _this = this;

    $(document).on("click", '.fa-list-ul', function(event) {
      console.log($(this).data('assignment'));
      $(".assignments__index__options__index").removeClass("hidden")
      $("body").addClass("openDropdown")
      event.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "body.openDropdown", function(event) {
      $(".assignments__index__options__index").addClass("hidden")
      $("body").removeClass("openDropdown")
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }
};
dashboard.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="assignments__index__card">

  <div class="assignments__index__options">
    <i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true" data-assignment="<%= assignment.id %>">CLICK HERE</i>

    <ul class="assignments__index__options__index <%= assignment.id %> hidden">
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Remove", account_assignment_path(assignment), method: :delete %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to "Edit", account_assignments_path %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```